# True Polymorph, Dragon Change Shape, and True Sight interaction

Tags: dnd-5e, simultaneous-effects

So what happens if one of my PC's casts True Polymorph to turn into an adult gold dragon, concentrates on the spell for the full hour to make it permanent, then uses the the dragons Change Shape feature to turn into some random humanoid. Would True Sight see only the original form of the PC, only the dragon form, 
or would it see both the dragon form and the original PC?

True Polymorph says (emphasis mine)

> ... If you concentrate on this spell for the full Duration, the **transformation becomes permanent**. ...

and then you add on another Magical Polymorph

> Change Shape: The dragon magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast...

Which means that the PC is now double Polymorphed, but since True Sight says

> ... and perceive the original form of a Shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic.

To me the wording of True Sight means that it sees only the original PC even if the transformation is permanent since it's still a magical effect, but I'm curious what either an official ruling has said and what you all think.

Comment: Hi Number268, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the site. This is a great first question! Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Creatures with True Sight see the PC

The wording on True Polymorph has changed in later printings and on D&D Beyond. It now says:

> If you concentrate on this spell for the full duration, the spell lasts until it is dispelled.

As a result it is clear that the PC is still under the effect of the spell (and thus transformed by magic).

The transformation of an Adult Gold Dragon states (***emphasis mine***):

> The dragon ***magically*** polymorphs into a humanoid that has a challenge rating no higher than its own, or back into its true form. [...]

You have quoted the correct portion of True Sight:

> [...] and perceive the original form of a shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic.

Importantly it states that creatures with True Sight can perceive the ***original*** form of the creature. This is distinct from the "true form" specified in the Adult Gold Dragon's Change Shape ability. It also pierces multiple layers of magical transformation.

Thus creature with True Sight see through *both* sets of magical transformations and see the PC.

Comment: Would that mean that someone or something with True Sight would know that the PC is polymorphed into a Dragon or does it see directly into the original bypassing the Dragon part?

Comment: @Number268 both

Comment: Can you explain how they would see the dragon form since your quote from truesight says you see the original form, nothing about intermediary forms?

Comment: @SeriousBri for the original form it says perceive not see. That distinction in wording is important (and intentional if the rest of the quote is taken in context, as it gives you the ability to *see* invisible creatures). More importantly, D&D is an exceptions based game, and true sight doesn't say it removes your ability to see the dragon form, just that you gain the ability to perceive the original form.

Comment: To clarify, the question as currently phrased, asks: can True Sight see the *intermediate* form, of "dragon", if the *original* form was a humanoid *and the current form is a humanoid*? If so, why? Based on what portion of the text, can we deduce this?